# PowerShell Add users to AD group via CSV - script not adding users

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

```
>     # Start transcript Start-Transcript -Path C:\Temp\Add-ADUsers.log -Append
> 
> # Import AD Module Import-Module ActiveDirectory
> 
> # Import the data from CSV file and assign it to variable $Users = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\jacktest.csv"
> 
> # Specify target group where the users will be added to
> # You can add the distinguishedName of the group. For example: CN=Pilot,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=exoip,DC=local $Group = "JackTest" 
> 
> foreach ($User in $Users) {
>     # Retrieve UPN
>     $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
> 
>     # Retrieve UPN related SamAccountName
>     $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UPN'" | Select-Object SamAccountName
> 
>     # User from CSV not in AD
>     if ($ADUser -eq $null) {
>         Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
>     }
>     else {
>         # Retrieve AD user group membership
>         $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $ADUser.SamAccountName | Select-Object Name
> 
>         # User already member of group
>         if ($ExistingGroups.Name -eq $Group) {
>             Write-Host "$UPN already exists in $Group" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
>         }
>         else {
>             # Add user to group
>             Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $ADUser.SamAccountName -WhatIf
>             Write-Host "Added $UPN to $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
>         }
>     } } Stop-Transcript
```

Code not add users to group successfully
I am trying to add 900+ users to an AD group from CSV with a heading "UserPrincipalName"
The reporting else if statements are working as expected.

Comment: PLEASE fix your code formatting.

Comment: Remove switch `-WhatIf` from the `Add-ADGroupMember` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is good enough and the reason for no changes made I believe is the `-WhatIf` switch , that should display a message and not do the action.

That aside, there are a couple of things you can consider, one is the `| Select-object` this would modify the object to `PSCustomObject` and you would loose all the methods and benefits of having an `ADObject`.
Another thing would be the comparison you use, instead of `-eq` againsta list you better use `-contains` , so you get true/false .
Third but not least is the comparison to `$null` , in that particular case I think you dont really need that, but you could rather just see if something is returned with `(-not $ADUser)`

With all that in mind, I have modify the code to my comments.

```
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    # Retrieve UPN
    $UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName

    # Retrieve UPN related SamAccountName
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UPN'"

    # User from CSV not in AD
    if (-not $ADUser) {
        Write-Host "$UPN does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        # Retrieve AD user group membership
        $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $ADUser.SamAccountName

        # User already member of group
        if ($ExistingGroups.Name -contains $Group) {
            Write-Host "$UPN already exists in $Group" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
        }
        else {
            # Add user to group
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $ADUser.SamAccountName
            Write-Host "Added $UPN to $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
    } 
} Stop-Transcript
```